# Cannot Restore Page with Something Went Wrong Error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, publishing-page, restore

I have a few pages that are showing "**Something Went Wrong**" Error.  The correlation id did not help.  Oh the error is on the version history tab for the page in site contents.

To fix the error I thought I could restore to the previous version using SharePoint Designer. I see all the versions and I highlight the one I want and select "**Previous Version**" but nothing happens.  Did I do something wrong? Is there another way that I can restore the pages besides using SharePoint Designer? Oh remember the page has errors in the version history too.  That may be the reason why I can't restore in designer.

If anyone can help would be awesome.  I really need these two pages or I may have to create a new page.

Comment: Do you have customization on these pages, for example, css, js? Do you see the error message on the page when opening it or is it displayed in the version history tab only? btw, the tag "2013" means you are using SharePoint 2013, right?

Comment: Yes there's css on the page.  The error message is on the when opening it and displayed in the version history tab too.  Yes 2013.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the whole error message you are getting.
Also in SP Designer, try editing the page in Advanced mode and check if the DocIdUrl contains the correct address of the page.

Comment: Thanks.  The whole error message reads "Something Went Wrong".  I did as you said with editing the page in Advanced mode and shows the incorrect url. Could this be causing the error?  How do I change? I noticed that the paged is checked out by another user too.  Would that cause the error too?

Comment: @SharePointLady Is there any possibility that the page has been edited by another user and there are conflicts in the content changes? Can you override this check out or can you ask the other user to check in the page and save the changes on the user’s end?